# How to overhear a neighbor mote Tx/Rx in Contiki?

Tags: packet-sniffers, contiki, neighbours, cooja

I want to know in **RPL** networks, after a node sends one packet to another node (for example *RPL-Collect/udp-sender*), how to know that intended node will forward this packet or not? I think **overhearing** neighbors transmission is needed, but is the another simple way to implemented this scenario in *Contiki/Cooja*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overhear packets in addition to normal operation you need to do several things:

1. Ensure that the radio is turned on and in the right channel. If you're using always-on CSMA or ContikiMAC you don't need to do anything special. Same for TSCH minimal schedule. Otherwise for TSCH you need to schedule a Rx cell with the right channel offset and in the right timeslot.
2. Somehow hack into the MAC layer to print or account packets not addressed to you - normally the MAC layer silently drops such packets.
3. Ensure hardware frame filtering is turned off (the radio is in promiscious mode).

Example:

```
radio_value_t radio_rx_mode;
/* Entering promiscuous mode so that the radio accepts all frames */
NETSTACK_RADIO.get_value(RADIO_PARAM_RX_MODE, &radio_rx_mode);
NETSTACK_RADIO.set_value(RADIO_PARAM_RX_MODE, radio_rx_mode & (~RADIO_RX_MODE_ADDRESS_FILTER));
```

If you just need to overhear packets and don't need the normal operation things and simpler. You can use [SenSniff](https://github.com/g-oikonomou/sensniff) then.

Comment: Excellent... Thanks @kfx. For example I want to know which mote in RPL don't forward received packets by **neighbors overhearing**. I considered your several things and that means I have several questions!

Comment: 1. I'm using **ContikiMAC**, by the way adding `NETSTACK_RDC.off(1)` in my process thread.

2. In `input_packet()` function in the **contikimac.c** I changed base statement that accepts all packets even not is destined to us, but I don't know how to print and accounted this buffered data for a few operations.

3. I think hardware frame filtering becoming turned off by set **CC2420_CONF_AUTOACK** to zero in **project-conf** _(promiscuous mode)_, by the way adding `NETSTACK_RADIO.set_value(RADIO_PARAM_RX_MODE, 0)` is operational?

What is your opinions?

Comment: @Hamed you still have problems with that? And no, autoack and frame filtering are two different settings. If think autoack will work even if frame filtering is off. So, don't turn off autoack. But if you need to for some reason, enable `CONTIKIMAC_CONF_SEND_SW_ACK`.

Comment: When entering **Promiscuous Mode**, _Packet Delivery Ratio_ drops considerably and udp-senders packets not delivered to sink at all. Within Timeline window in my **Cooja** simulation _interfered_ observed increasingly. Is there any solution to this or another way to listen to other neighbors?

Comment: That is strange. Are you sure you don't change the autoack settings? Just the frame filtering, right?

Comment: Yes @kfx, I think I need only disable `Address Filter` (RF Frame Filtering) and enable `Automatic Acknowledgments`. How to do that perfectly?